# How can I print unicode characters in LaTeX?

Tags: utf-8, latex, special-characters, xelatex

I need to print a bunch of unicode characters using LaTeX, and cannot find a solution.

Here is the simplest (not)working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Test: $\beta$ βᵝᵦꞵ

\end{document}
```

The output is:

```
Test: β              with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTex
```

With PdfLaTex I get the standard error:

> Package inputenc error: Unicode character (...) not set up for use with LaTex

I am aware of the possibility to re-define all unicode characters to a single stndardized one, that of `\beta`. However, that is not the solution, as I need to print the characters exactly as displayed above or in any decent text editor.

The file I use is encoded in UTF-8. I am using TexMaker, also set-up for UTF-8.

Comment: In principal your code works fine for lualatex or xelatex, you'll just need to find a font that has all your symbols. With `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}` you can show some of them

Comment: That's what I thought, too. However, I couldn't find any font that has all the symbols. That's why I doubt that this is the solution, because when I use the same font as the text editors use I still don't have the characters displayed, but the text editors do just fine. Or a web browser, here.